# What could be the elementary divisors of subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, free-abelian-group

> What can be the elementary divisors of subgroup $H \le \mathbb{Z}^2$ of index $36$?

I can't see what's the connection between the index and the elementary divisors?

As far as I know, elementary divisors are based on the basis of free group, and has nothing to do with the index. For a given basis, the elementary divisors of subgroup are natural numbers so that each number divides the next, and multiplying the basis by those numbers gives us a new basis for the second group.

What's the connection?

Comment: Duplicate of -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894917/elementary-divisors-of-a-subgroup-of-mathbbz2-of-index-36 (I can't mark my own question as duplicate, since the other question doesn't have an accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The question can be rephrased as follows:

> What are the possible abelian groups of order $36$?

and then applied to $\mathbb{Z}^2/H$.

Comment: Why can it be rephrased like that?